# Please help out in changing a horizontal css dropdown menu into vertical dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a horizontal CSS dropdown menu here, got it from net.
I've searched a whole day on how to convert this horizontal menu to a Vertical dropdown menu.
and how to make sub-menu's out of it.
So guys please help me out if it's possible.

Here's the CSS `styles.css`:

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  color: #333333;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #eeeeee;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a {
  background: #d9d9d9 url(images/grad_light.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d9d9d9), color-stop(100%, #bfbfbf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d9d9d9', endColorstr='#bfbfbf', GradientType=0);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #979797, inset 0 10px 10px #979797;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #979797, inset 0 10px 10px #979797;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #979797, inset 0 10px 10px #979797;
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active a:hover {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d9d9d9), color-stop(100%, #bfbfbf));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#d9d9d9', endColorstr='#bfbfbf', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
  background: #bfbfbf url(images/grad_light.png) repeat-x left top;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(50%, #e5e5e5), color-stop(51%, #d7d7d7), color-stop(100%, #ededed));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 50%, #d7d7d7 51%, #ededed 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-right: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  line-height: 34px;
  padding: 0 35px;
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #ffffff url(images/grad_light.png) repeat-x left bottom;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d9d9d9), color-stop(50%, #bfbfbf), color-stop(51%, #b0b0b0), color-stop(100%, #c7c7c7));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9d9d9 0%, #bfbfbf 50%, #b0b0b0 51%, #c7c7c7 100%);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed', GradientType=0);
  filter: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 36px;
  left: -1px;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  *width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  border-top: 0 none;
  border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 9px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And Here's the `HTML`

```
<head>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active '><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally you have to show some work that you tried. But I'm guessing you have no clue on what is with that css.

You only need to modify your css, add this after your css:

```css
#cssmenu ul {
  width:200px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  top: -1px;
  left: 200px;
}
#cssmenu a {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  border-top: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DRACa/)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that HTML only contains content, not style. This means you can remove the CSS and be left with just an unordered list, which is good semantic markup for any sort of menu. From there, use new CSS to build it up into a vertical menu, or anything really. If you want, you could follow a CSS tutorial for making the type of menu you want, since any tutorial should start with HTML that looks similar to yours.

(While we're discussing semantics, though, I should point out that all the `span`s and the wrapper `div` are unnecessary, and a working menu can be created without them.)